# Loop over a reference object multiple times to copy its properties to other objects in Javascript/Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have an array of objects called arr1:

```
[{a:1, b:2, c:3, type:1}, {c:1, type:2}, {d:1, e:2, type:2}]
```

The objects in it share a property called 'type' with other objects in the array arr2:

```
[{d:1, e:2, type:1}, {a:1, b:2, type:2}]
```

How can I refer to the 'type' property to copy arr2's remaining properties into arr1? The desired result would be:

```
[{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:1, e:2 type:1}, {a:1, b:2, c:1, type:2}, {a:1, b:2, d:1, e:2, type:2}]
```

When I use something like angular.extend([], arr1, arr2), it only copies arr2's properties into the first 2 objects in arr1 (the 3rd object doesn't get love). What am I missing? Advanced thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I'm using functions only available in newer browsers, so if you need to support old ones, you'll have to look into polyfills or use a library.

```js
var a = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, type:1}, {c:1, type:2}, {d:1, e:2, type:2}];
var b = [{d:1, e:2, type:1}, {a:1, b:2, type:2}];

// get an array of all types -- [1, 2, 2]
var types = a.map(function(o) {
  return o.type
});
// filter it down to unique types -- [1, 2]
types = types.filter(function(type, i) {
  return i === types.indexOf(type);
});

var list = [];

// loop through first array
angular.forEach(a, function(o) {
  // get all objects that match type: x
  var matches = b.filter(function(match) {
    return o.type === match.type;
  });

  matches.unshift({});
  matches.unshift(o);
  // merge all matches into object from first array
  var merged = angular.extend.apply(this, matches);

  list.push(merged);
});

console.log(list)

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Nicely done, this helped me so much. Curious about that new unshift function you used and the .apply() that you put on angular.extend() using 'this': how does all of that work together?

Comment: unshift adds an item to the beginning of an array, like reverse of `.push()`.. `.apply` lets you use an array as the arguments, so it's like `angular.extend({}, o, a, b, c, d...)` however many items there are